# Can ControllerSaleOrder controller fetch more data in index() in opencart?

Tags: php, controller, opencart

Here is a part of my ControllerSaleOrder class,

```
class ControllerSaleOrder extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('sale/order');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('sale/order');

        $this->getList();
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there a method available like `$this->getForm();` to preload data?

Comment: Please give more information on your question

Comment: Like can we preload the data here itself ?

Comment: yes you can but usually the getList function is reused in multiple functions hence it is defined seperately to get data